# I am getting getting SSL handshake issue How to disable ssl in karate

Tags: karate

When I am trying to access a secure endpoint, I am getting SSL handshake exception even after I disable ssl by using the following karate ways.

option1) declared the following in feature file
* configure ssl = true

option2) declared the following in karate-config.js

karate.configure('ssl', { trustAll: true });
              (or)
karate.configure('ssl', true);

Exception:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you missed to make the `url` start with `https`, or vice-versa.

If you still have issues, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Do we found the solution for this issue - I  am facing similar kind of issues for newly created domain in application old domains it working fine without any issues.